# Select on change

Tags: forms, 8, navigation

With Drupal 8, I have a form with two selects, both filled. I want to add a button/link after each of these two selects, looking like this.

```
[__SELECT__v][BUTTON]
[__SELECT__v][BUTTON]
```

The buttons, however, don't have a fixed link because the link target depends on what is selected in the select. Also, the link needs to open a new tab.

For example, if in the select "car1"  the key "12345" is selected, the link should open /cars/12345; if "car2" is selected with the key 
"67890" then "/cars/67890"

This is the code I am using.

```
$form['select_g1'] = array(
                    '#type' => 'select',
                    '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline">',
                    '#title' => t('Select &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;&emsp;'),
                    '#options' => $contarray,
                    '#empty_value' => '',
                    '#default_value' => ($ext) ? $row['model'] : "",
                    );
$form['button'] = array(
                    '#markup' => ' <a target="_blank" href=""><span class="button js-form-submit form-submit"><img src="/sites/default/buttons/edit.png"></span></a></div>',              
                    );
```

Can someone help me there?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do with javascript.

You can do an onchange event for your select that updates the link,

or you can do a mousedown event on your link that grabs the value from the select.

A quick google search shows many possibilities:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758659/compose-a-link-based-in-selects-option-value

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357075/how-to-update-append-to-it-an-href-based-on-dropdown-selection

To add javascript to your form, you need to add the js to your custom module, say in mymodule/js/updatelink.js

then add a mymodule.libraries.yml file in your module

```
mymodule.updatelink:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/updatelink.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
```

then attach it to your form like this:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mymodule.updatelink';
```

You'll want to wrap your code in a Drupal.behaviors class.  See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: Thank you very much! So far it works with including the js and (for testing) displaying a alert when the select changes.